# Realtime gnuplotting with python pipes and multiple plots

Tags: python, r, plot, gnuplot

I need to update several plots of gnuplot in real time data streaming. I have written a working program but I don't like it.

```
import subprocess32 as sbp
plot = sbp.Popen(['gnuplot','-persist'], stdin = sbp.PIPE, stdout=sbp.PIPE, stderr = sbp.PIPE)

#realtime simulator

data = []
for x in range(10):
    data.append((x,x*x))
    print data
    plot.stdin.write("plot '-' with lines\n")  
    #print "\n".join("%f %f"%d for d in data)
    plot.stdin.write("\n".join("%f %f"%d for d in data).encode())
    plot.stdin.write("\ne\n")  
    sleep (0.8)
sleep (20)
```

It redraws the whole array after every addition of a new value. What if there are 100 000 elements? I think it is very costly to cycle them in python. I have found in documentation the `replot` command which adds data to previous gnuplot command, but it is incompatible with multiple plots. So how is it possible to add new coordinates in a plot without cycle through the whole data array?

Comment: You can't, because gnuplot itself doesn't save any data. You cannot add new point also replot rereads its given input source. So yes, you must always send all data you want to plot.

Comment: @Christoph What about adding new data points via multiplot (assuming the ranges don't change)? I can't check now but maybe that'd work.

Comment: @Miguel Yes, in that case this could work, haven't checked it. I was thinking of sending the data as heredoc (Version 5), and each time create a new one and plot it with `replot`. Don't know about the performance of this. Best option is probably still to use good old temp file

Comment: @Christoph In the case of the temp file, maybe one can store it in memory with tmpfs to have faster I/O.

Comment: Io is faster (as of my feelings) + Multiplot is interesting idea. Will try. Thanks.

Comment: I found tempfile.SpooledTemporaryFile. It creates in memory file but how can I pass it to gnuplot?

Comment: @user3003873 If you are successful in any of your attempts, please consider answering you own question here with the solution.